# Object matching query does not exist when try to delete object

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

When I try to delete Comany (model) with related objects, I get strange exception:
    Object matching query does not exist when try to delete object

```
company =  Company.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('id'))
company.delete() //on this line
```

Could you please explain what could be issues, as django should delete related objects by default?

Comment: are you sure your object with this id exist?

Comment: Yes, error happens when I try to delete it.

Comment: method get retuns object and not exception happens

Comment: This error was because of using post_delete signal, it tried to access  data that was already deleted and unaccessible.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 7):

This error was because of using post_delete signal, it tried to access data that was already deleted and unaccessible.